# Laravel Validation: Nested properties not throwing validation error if missing from payload

Tags: laravel, validation

I'm sending back an object which requires some validation:

##### Payload

```json
{
    "name": "Foobar",
    "info": {
        "type": "chemical",
        "cas": "001"
    }
}
```

##### Validation

```php
'info.type' => ['required', 'string'],
'info.cas'  => Rule::requiredIf(request()->info['type'] === 'Chemical'),
```

If the `type` property doesn't exist on the payload, the validation (`info.type`) doesn't even trigger. Is this an expected behaviour?

If this is how validation works, how can I get the validation to actually run for it if the payload doesn't include it?

Comment: Well, to answer you in a round about way, to address this issue, I'm always ensuring that I send the property `type` in the payload.

Comment: Funny how my comments get removed? Hmm well .. could I see the form inputs? You are defining the input name like `name="info[type]"` without single quotes and not like `info['type']`, it's a common mistake quickly overlooked.

Comment: @dbf yeah weird about your comment...

The FE is a Vue app and referenced is like `v-model="info.type"` on the input field.

Comment: And the payload above is a dump from `$request->all()`?

Comment: @bdf Not quite. It is a FormRequest class

Comment: Oddly enough, this validation works as expected in the tinker console. Can you check what is returned when you add this method to your form request? `protected function prepareForValidation() { dd($this->all()); }`